# Focus Cursor function JavaScript (code included)

Tags: javascript, forms, focus

Here is my javascript code for a cursor focus function to go to username if it is blank on a form call "login".

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
if (document.forms.login.user.value == "")
(
    document.forms.login.user.focus();
)   
else
(
    document.forms.login.password.focus();
)
```

Do I need to add anything to my form? Here it is.

```
<form action="form.php" method="post" name="login">
<label for="user"><b>Username:</b></label> <input name="user" type="text" id="user" size="20"/><br/>
<label for="password"><b>Password:</b></label> <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="20"/><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="login"/><br/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. (Removed the parentheses around the actual if and else sections.)

```
if (document.forms.login.user.value == "")
    document.forms.login.user.focus();
else
    document.forms.login.password.focus();
```

### Working Example

http://jsfiddle.net/S8bRL/

Comment: thanks! I actually got it to work by using "{}" instead of "()"

Comment: Yeah, the `{}` are optional if you're only running one command after the `if/else`, but are required if you're running multiple after the `if/else`.

Comment: @tim: that is because `()` is improper syntax